'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file' after resolving merge conflicts
I have a NodeJs v18.17.1 installed on my Windows PC as well as nvm 1.1.11 to switch between node versions and npm v9.6.7. I am able to run a project without aby problems yet when I attempt to merge branch 'a' into branch 'b' and some conflicts occur - after I resolve them - and try to git merge --continue I get an error
'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
This is the only scenario when this error occurs.
Did anyone experienced the same problem? If so what was your solution to it?
I tried deleting and reinstalling node from scratch and still to no avail. I also verified my PATH variables - they seem fine as well.
I have C:\Program Files\nodejs; in both my System and User PATHS.

In the terminal where you run git merge --continue, if you run node --version does it return anything to you?
